# can you use a colon in a key for a lua table

Tags: lua, computercraft

So I'm writing a program for the minecraft mod computercraft. I wanted to know if it was possible to do something like this:

```
tbl = {}
var = "minecraft:dirt"
tbl[var] = {pos ={0,0,0,1}}
```

For some reason I feel it doesnt save this table correctly so when I go to do

```
print(tbl["minecraft:dirt"].pos[4])
```

it errors

Can you use colons in keys?

Comment: Probably a typo.  Runs fine here.  What error are you seeing?

Comment: `Can you use colons in keys?` - You can use arbitrary strings as keys.

Answer (score 3):

```
tbl = {}
var = "minecraft:dirt"
tbl[var] = {pos ={0,0,0,1}}
print(tbl["minecraft:dirt"].pos[4])
```

prints `1`

This is syntactically correct and should not result in any error message.

The only thing that won't work with colon is the syntactic sugar `tbl.minecraft:dirt` as Lua names may not contain colons. But if you use it like that `tbl["minecraft:dirt"]` colon is perfectly fine.

Long story short: Yes you can use colons in table keys.